# How do i get comma separated UserID with contact company id from input json array

Tags: java, json

I have array of json objects in each object i have UserID,ContactCompanyID and UserType if the UserType is internal then there is no ContactCompanyID if it is external there must be ContactCompanyID below is my sample input

```
JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray();       
    String CompanyID="1127";
    String ProjectID="1854";

    JSONObject j1=new JSONObject();
    j1.put("UserID", "1");
    j1.put("ContactCompanyID", "1");
    j1.put("UserType", "External");

    JSONObject j2=new JSONObject();
    j2.put("UserID", "2");
    j2.put("ContactCompanyID", "1");
    j2.put("UserType", "External");

    JSONObject j3=new JSONObject();
    j3.put("UserID", "3");
    j3.put("ContactCompanyID", "1");
    j3.put("UserType", "External");

    JSONObject j4=new JSONObject();
    j4.put("UserID", "4");
    j4.put("ContactCompanyID", "2");
    j4.put("UserType", "External");

    JSONObject j5=new JSONObject();
    j5.put("UserID", "5");
    j5.put("ContactCompanyID", "3");
    j5.put("UserType", "External");

    JSONObject j6=new JSONObject();
    j6.put("UserID", "6");
    j6.put("ContactCompanyID", "");
    j6.put("UserType", "Internal");

    JSONObject j7=new JSONObject();
    j7.put("UserID", "7");
    j7.put("ContactCompanyID", "");
    j7.put("UserType", "Internal");

    JSONObject j8=new JSONObject();
    j8.put("UserID", "8");
    j8.put("ContactCompanyID", "");
    j8.put("UserType", "Internal");

    jArray.put(j1);
    jArray.put(j2);
    jArray.put(j3);
    jArray.put(j4);
    jArray.put(j5);
    jArray.put(j6);
    jArray.put(j7);
    jArray.put(j8);
```

How do i get the comma separated total internal users and comma separated same contact company users

below is my expected output

```
[{
        "CompanyID": "1127",
        "UserID": "6,7,8",
        "ContactCompanyID": "",
        "ProjectID": "1854"
    },
    {
        "CompanyID": "1127",
        "UserID": "1,2,3",
        "ContactCompanyID": "1",
        "ProjectID": "1854"
    },
    {
        "CompanyID": "1127",
        "UserID": "4",
        "ContactCompanyID": "2",
        "ProjectID": "1854"
    },
    {
        "CompanyID": "1127",
        "UserID": "5",
        "ContactCompanyID": "3",
        "ProjectID": "1854"
    }
]
```

Comment: Is there any reason why the values for `UserID` have to be `String`?  From a JSON point of view, it would make sense to have them be an `Array` object.

Comment: @Carlos ya its necessary to avoid multiple database call